# What is the replacement of drupal_match_path()?

Tags: path-aliases

What is the replacement of `drupal_match_path()` in Drupal 8?
The following function is removed from Drupal 8. How can I achieve same functionality in Drupal 8?

```
function drupal_match_path($path, $patterns) {
  $regexps = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);

  if (!isset($regexps[$patterns])) {
    // Convert path settings to a regular expression.
    // Therefore replace newlines with a logical or, /* with asterisks and the <front> with the frontpage.
    $to_replace = array(
      '/(\r\n?|\n)/', // newlines
      '/\\\\\*/', // asterisks
      '/(^|\|)\\\\<front\\\\>($|\|)/', // <front>
    );
    $replacements = array(
      '|',
      '.*',
      '\1' . preg_quote(config('system.site')->get('page.front'), '/') . '\2',
    );
    $patterns_quoted = preg_quote($patterns, '/');
    $regexps[$patterns] = '/^(' . preg_replace($to_replace, $replacements, $patterns_quoted) . ')$/';
  }
  return (bool) preg_match($regexps[$patterns], $path);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[New PathMatcher service](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274675) reports that the path.matcher service was introduced to deprecate most procedural functions in the path.inc file with its methods.
In particular, the equivalent of `$path_matches = drupal_match_path($path, $patterns);` is the following code.

```
$path_matches = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->matchPath($path, $patterns);
```

The same service is used to check if the currently viewed page is the front page.

```
$is_front = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();
```

As usual, injecting the dependency is preferred over calling `\Drupal::service()`.

Comment: Is there any need to include `'@path.matcher'` service in mymodule.service.yml?

Comment: If you have a service that depends on path.matcher, you can declare it as dependency. Then the question would be "Do I need to create a service?" That depends from the code you are writing. Notice also that, if you have a form, you can inject its dependencies too.

Comment: How can I inject this dependency ?

Comment: It depends from the code you are using. That is a different question, though.

Comment: For database operations I used '@database' as argument in service.yml. Can I inject this service as well?I have a simple form with CRUD operations.

Comment: Sure. If you are already injecting a service, you can inject also another one, and more.